# More idioms like "needle in a haystack" relevant to hidden/hard to find items?

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

Are there more idioms, sayings or phrases similar to "needle in a haystack" that are relevant to hidden objects, or difficult to find items?

Also interested in similar nouns relevant to the somewhat oppositional concepts like "needle" and "haystack" or "3-leaf clover" vs. "4-leaf clover" where one object is significantly harder to find.

Comment: There is also [No Leaf Clover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Leaf_Clover).

Comment: Your imagination is the only thing that sets the limits here. For example: "It's like looking for a hymen in a whorehouse / an honest man in Congress / a unicorn in a forest of pricks / fur on a rattlesnake / balls on a cow / John Boehner's stain-remover spray / pubes on an egg".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a one-word answer:

Waldo

Answer (score 4):

"Looking for a black cat in a coal cellar"?

Comment: That's a new one. Very colourful!

Comment: Similarly "looking for a white cat (or polar bear, or whatever) in a snowstorm".

Comment: This sounds like a historical phrase, rather than current usage. Like something someone my grandparents generation would say. Interesting nonetheless so +1!

Comment: Well, it's been a while since we've had coal cellars...

Answer (score 3):

If you take "hard to find" as being "very rare/non-existent" …

"Scarce as hen's teeth."