# Expression for a rare find?

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression along the lines of

> Red cars, for the man, were like the birdwatcher's spatuletail

... assuming the spatuletail is a rare find for birdwatchers. I'm pretty sure I heard something like this not too long ago, but I can't remember what. It was definitely in that format - the profession and then something someone in the profession looks for, is unexpected to come across.

edit: I think I'm starting to recall that the expression was more along the lines of

> the archaeologist's El Dorado

..or something similar, where it means a unique breakthrough or meaningful discovery of a field rather than an uncommon but still ordinary find.

Still though, I would like to know if there's an expression similar to the one in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean 'difficult to locate/find', rather than 'rare'. The commonest idiom for objects difficult to locate is **needle in a haystack**.

> Red cars, for the man, were like needles in a haystack.

This means the man found red cars very difficult to spot.

There are several related idioms for things that are hard to chance upon. A couple of them ([also mentioned here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/more-idioms-like-needle-in-a-haystack-relevant-to-hidden-hard-to-find-items)):

- **scarce as hen's teeth**
- **black cat in a coal cellar**

Comment: When I hear "needle in a haystack," I think of something difficult to locate, not necessarily rare.  (After all, the problem isn't the rarity of needles – the issue is the surrounding hay).

Comment: @J.R. That's true, but I reckon in the OP's sentence red cars are difficult to find, rather than rare. Also am editing my answer slightly...

Comment: The O.P. could perhaps improve the question – red cars aren't particularly rare _or_ hard to find.  Maybe something like a red Lamborghini would be more like "the birdwatcher's spatuletail."  As for _needle in a haystack_, that often implies a frustrating search, like when you can't remember where you parked your car at the mall, and the 30-minute search was like "looking for a needle in a haystack."

Answer (score 1):

*Seeking El Dorado* can mean looking for something that may be just a legend or an illusion or for something that may never be found. According to the Wikepedia article on [El Dorado, the legendary "Lost City of Gold":](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Dorado)

> El Dorado is also sometimes used as a metaphor to represent an ultimate prize or "Holy Grail" that one might spend one's life seeking. It could represent true love, heaven, happiness, or success. It is used sometimes as a figure of speech to represent something much sought after that may not even exist, or, at least, may not ever be found. Such use is evident in [Poe's poem "El Dorado"](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/eldorado/). In this context, El Dorado bears similarity to other myths such as the Fountain of Youth and Shangri-la.

This dictionary entry under the word [rarity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rarity) has a list of comparative quotes that might have something you could use, such as:

> *Rare as a man without self-pity* —Stephen Vincent Benét
>
> *Rare as a politician who lives up to his campaign promises*.
>
> *[Money … was as] scarce as frogs’ teeth, crabs’ tails or eunuchs’ whiskers* —Pat Barr
>
> (Barr’s colorful multiple simile refers to the scarcity of money in Korea during the late nineteenth century when the heroine of her book, *Curious Life For a Lady*, was there.)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using **Rare to come by**, which has an idiomatic feel to it, but is certainly far from being a metaphor, like the one with El Dorado.

Answer (score -1):

Quantum leap
    boost, development, discovery, find, finding, gain, hike, improvement, increase, invention, leap, progress, quantum leap, rise, step forward

avant-garde, breakthrough , cutting-edge, excellent, exceptional, extreme, first, foremost, forward, higher, late, leading, leading-edge, liberal, precocious, progressive, radical, state-of-the-art*, unconventional

:-)

Comment: Not an answer to the question at hand, and frankly I have trouble coming up with any question to which it is.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8: A few of these terms are indeed related to "a _unique breakthrough_ or _meaningful discovery in a field_," which was part of the O.P.'s request.  That said, I agree that this answer should be pruned a bit, and elaborated upon.